# Should I use weighted average to deal with category size problems in a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, unbalanced-classes, weights

I am trying to see the effect of retirement benefits on the late-career intentions for business. The retired employees are categorized on the basis of retirement benefits. The first category is low, the second is medium, and the third is high benefits.

The number of people under the 3rd category is a lot more than the first two categories as you can see in the table attached here. Should I use weighted values? If so, how should I use them?

The crosstab with business intent is also shown:

[image]

The correlation and significance are both okay in the present scenario but I don't know what will be the effect under weighted category, and how it would interact with other IV's on normal scale.

Comment: What are you trying to predict?

Comment: Late-career entrepreneurial intention is the DV and the independent variables are prior business experience, qualification, business ties and gender.

Answer (score 1):

To present a marginal relationship is very problematic.  For example, you are not adjusting even for age.  But to your question, weighting by necessity will up-weight some categories and down-weight others, and there is no statistical basis for weighting here.  To down-weight existing data effectively reduces the sample size and results in a loss of precision.  You are stuck with the observed frequencies.  If you want more information for the two low-frequency categories, you'll have to go out and get more samples.

Comment: Sir, I have the same thing in my mind that I may need more samples here. However how many are needed? Secondly, I may add here that the three groups carry different ages, experiences and qualification levels and I am also using these demographic variables alongside. So in that case still I need more samples or not?

Comment: One guidance is that to estimate a single probability with 0.95 confidence to within a +/- 0.1 margin of error requires n=96.  So think of 96 as a minimum cell size for getting semi-reliable probability estimates.